# findViewById Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-widget, datepicker, nullpointerexception

Dear Stack Overflow Community,

I'm attempting to get the date from a datepicker and set it as a string with code located outside the onCreate method. Here is my code:

```
DatePicker dp =(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerControl);
String date_picker_message= (dp.getMonth()+1) +"/"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dp.getYear() ;
```

However, when I try to utilize this code, it complies without error but crashes with this message:

03-30 22:51:20.719: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I think it could be because I haven't set the content view and my code is attempting to find a view that does not yet exist. But how would I do this outside the onCreate method?

If I'm screaming down the highway of wrongness, please let me know and direct me towards the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Post layout file and full onCreate() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank all of you for your answers! The issue was resolved on my part. The goal was to get the value of a date picker and use this value in a SQL WHERE statement. I thoroughly dislike variables placed haphazardly in code while the method that uses this variable is located entirely elsewhere. Logically grouping the variables and the methods that use them makes sense to me.

The code below is how I resolved the issue.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.show_events:
        try {
            DatePicker dp=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerControl);

            if ((dp.getMonth()+1) < 10) {

                String date_picker_value = "0"+( dp.getMonth()+1) +"/"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dp.getYear();
                Cursor cursor = getEvents(date_picker_value);
                showEvents(cursor);
                Toast.makeText(view.this, date_picker_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {

                String date_picker_value = ( dp.getMonth()+1) +"/"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dp.getYear();
                String date_picker_value="Showing events for: " + date_picker_value;
                Cursor cursor = getEvents(date_picker_value);
                showEvents(cursor);
                Toast.makeText(view.this, date_picker_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
        finally {
            events.close();
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DatePicker dp =(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerControl);
```

Declare Date Picker inside your class...
Initialize it inside on create method.
Use it anywhere you like.

Sample Code:

```
public class youractivity extends Activity {
DatePicker dp;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  dp =(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerControl);
}
private return_type yourmethod(Arguments)
{
 String date_picker_message= (dp.getMonth()+1) +"/"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dp.getYear() ;
}
}
```

Comment: in this case it could be appropriate to check on null dp object, catch or throw NullPointerException in place you use the object.

But anyway I can't understand the purpose of useing view that was not created

Comment: You have to post clearly.. Have you solved the issue? In that case select an appropriate answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should registrer onClick listener for the DatePicker. You can read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)
 tutorial.